# Grid Combinations with Positive and Negative Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

If there is an $n$ by $n$ matrix where each element is either 1 or -1, how many unique matrices are there such that each row and each column multiplies to 1?

I solved for the trivial case of $n = 2$, which is 2. However, for larger $n$, I'm not sure how to find a systematic way to count. I have tried using the fact that you can transform an existing correct matrix into another correct matrix by selecting 4 points that form a rectangle to all become negative, but I am not sure how I could count these in an organized way.

Comment: "how many unique matrices are there"???

Comment: @Leon The question seems to be just number of square n by n matrices (all entries $\pm 1$) where if entries of any column are multiplied, result is $1,$ and same thing for rows. I don't think "unique" means any more than distinct.

Comment: The issue is equivalent to find $(0-1)$ matrices with an even number of ones in each row and column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each row can have $1$'s & $-1$'s in $2^{n-1}$ ways. Fill in the first $n-1$ rows & then complete the last row to give each column a positive parity. So there are $\color{red}{2^{(n-1)^2}}$ ways to construct these matricies.

Answer (score 3):

Consider any $(n-1) \times (n-1) $ minor.
This could be filled with any option of $ \pm 1$.

Claim: The unfilled cells are uniquely determined by the column / row that they are in, and there is no conflict.

Proof: Do it yourself.

Corollary: There are $ 2^{(n-1)^2 } $ ways to fill up the matrix.